# SQL Server where clause with null column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an `Employee` table and how it works is, when a new employee is added, the column `[DOR]` will be null and `[Status]` will be 1. When the employee is being relieved from the company, the `[DOR]` column value will be the date which he/she left the company and `[Status]` is set to 0.

I need to fetch the details of all the employees who were available in a given date. The employees with `Status` as 1 and those who are not yet relieved till that date have to be fetched.

But I am not able to do the same as when equating with `DOR`, its null value and not returning any of the rows.

[image: Data in Employee table]

If I give the input as `2015-02-10`, it should fetch the two records and when I give `2015-02-15`, it should fetch only first record.

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee]
(
    [EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Contact] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DOJ] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DOR] [date] NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [Name], [RoleId], [Email], [Contact], [DOJ], [DOR], [Status], [Salary])  
VALUES (1001, N'Employee 1', 3, N'', N'', CAST(0x8D390B00 AS Date), NULL, 1, CAST(6000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))

INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [Name], [RoleId], [Email], [Contact], [DOJ], [DOR], [Status], [Salary]) 
VALUES (1002, N'Employee 2', 7, N'', N'', CAST(0x8D390B00 AS Date), CAST(0x9A390B00 AS Date), 0, CAST(4000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `IS NULL` operator instead of `= NULL` in your condition, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE DOJ <= '2015-02-15'
  AND (DOR IS NULL OR DOR > '2015-02-15')
```

Comment: Ohhh, Thanks a lot, mate! I've been scratching my head over this for last 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select
    EmployeeId,
    Name
from 
    Employee 
where
    DOJ <= @searchDate and 
    (DOR is null or DOR > @searchDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE @dateOfSearch BETWEEN DOJ and COALESCE(DOR, '2099-12-31')
```

What this query does, is it checks if the search date is between start date and end date. If end date is `null` then `COALESCE` function is used to take the very high value date.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of the previous answers :-)

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE @dateOfSearch BETWEEN DOJ and COALESCE(DOR, @dateOfSearch)
```